# Are rotations generated by translations, scalar multiplications and inversions?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I read a paper saying the Mobius transformation from $\mathbb{R}^n\cup \infty \to \mathbb{R}^n\cup \infty$is generated by translations, scalar multiplications and inversions $x\to \frac{x}{|x|^2}$. So how do we get rotations from above mentioned generators?

Comment: The rotations of the Riemann sphere that fix infinity are exactly given by scalar multiplication by a complex number of modulus 1 away from infinity.

Comment: As evinced by the answers, your question was not clear enough!

Answer (score 8):

$$e^{i \theta} + \frac{1}{-e^{-i \theta} + \frac{1}{e^{i \theta} + \frac{1}{z}}} = - e^{2 i \theta} z.$$

Thus, any rotation is a composition of translations and inversions.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear: what do you mean by "do we need" ? Moreover, inversions are not usually considered as Moebius transformation (they do not preserve orientation), and finally you do not precise what scalars you consider (real or complex).

Yet, I guess that one of the two following facts should answer your question: multiplication by a complex scalar is a similarity (a rotation if the number has modulus $1$), and the composition of two reflexions (which are inversions with respect to lines, which are circles containing the point at infinity) is a rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Moebius Transformation is kind of group action obtained by homomorphism between complex matrices 2x2 and linear fractions of the shape

$
f(z) = \frac{(az +b)}{(cz+d)}
$

It works in case of complex numbers but it is different from general rotation group. It is only kind of *representation* for certain dimension. So i case of Riemann sphere indeed You do not need rotations, You may use only mentioned by You symmetries, whilst in general case different representations are needed.